# Is there a way to change the sentiment score for a word in AFINN lexicon?

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

I'm doing a sentiment analysis on text in the r/travel subreddit and for obvious reasons, the word 'negative' is attached with a negative sentiment score. In this specific context, a negative test result is actually a positive thing so I would like to know if there is a way to change the score in the lexicon, in hopes to change the overall score.
ChatGPT gave the following method, but R doesn't recognize the library 'afinn'.

```
library(afinn)

# Modify the sentiment score for a word (e.g., "happy")
afinn$word_scores["happy"] <- 5
```

Comment: What's the code you are using to perform the sentiment analsys? Maybe `afinn <- textdata::lexicon_afinn()` will give you what you want. But it's not clear where you want to use those values after you change them.

Comment: I am using afinn to get a sentiment score for texts in reddit comments. 

`df_afinn <- tokenized_text %>% 
  inner_join(get_sentiments("afinn")) %>% 
  group_by(index = id) %>% 
  summarise(sentiment = sum(value)) %>% 
  mutate(method = "AFINN") `

Note, the ID here is a date. I use this to plot sentiment over time.

Comment: Storing scores from the lexicon in a list, I could change the score using the following code:
`afinn <- textdata::lexicon_afinn()
afinn[afinn$word == "negative", "value"] <- 2`